# YouTube Live Streaming API: LiveChatMessages userBannedEvent not showing

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm currently creating a script that handles the ban events when a user is banned from a YouTube live chat, however the event is never emitted when a user is banned (even when I have mod perms on the stream). For authorization I'm using the `youtube.force-ssl` scope, but I still don't get the event, only textMessageEvent. Am I passing the improper permission/scope?

For anyone wondering, here's the code I'm using :)
I'm using a modified version of https://github.com/yuta0801/youtube-live-chat (made it so I could pass an authorization token and passing it in the request headers)

```js
const YouTube = require('youtube-live-chat');

const yt = new YouTube("CHANNEL_ID", "API_KEY", "AUTH_TOKEN")
yt.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('ready!')
  yt.listen(5000)
})

yt.on('message', data => {
  console.log(data.snippet.type)
})

yt.on('error', error => {
  console.error(error)
})
```

request function in the lib that I modified

```js
  request(url, callback) {
    let options = {
      url: url,
      method: 'GET',
      json: true,
      headers: {}
    }
    if(this.auth) options.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${this.auth}`

    request(options, (error, response, data) => {
      if (error)
        this.emit('error', error)
      else if (response.statusCode !== 200)
        this.emit('error', data)
      else
        callback(data)
    })
  }
```

[scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gj5WA.png)

[eventLog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwjg2.png)

Comment: Please paste code snippet and console output in post directly, not image, see: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: fixed, thanks @CalosKao :)